# Handling nested elements with Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Given the simple XML data below:

```
<book>
   <title>My First Book</title>
   <abstract>
         <para>First paragraph of the abstract</para>
         <para>Second paragraph of the abstract</para>
    </abstract>
    <keywordSet>
         <keyword>First keyword</keyword>
         <keyword>Second keyword</keyword>
         <keyword>Third keyword</keyword>
    </keywordSet>
</book>
```

How can I traverse the tree, using [lxml](http://lxml.de), and get all paragraphs in the "abstract" element, as well as all keywords in the "keywordSet" element?

The code snippet below returns only the first line of text in each element:

```
from lxml import objectify
root = objectify.fromstring(xml_string) # xml_string contains the XML data above
print root.title # returns the book title
for line in root.abstract:
    print line.para # returns only yhe first paragraph
for word in root.keywordSet:
    print word.keyword # returns only the first keyword in the set
```

I tried to follow [this example](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/07/example-parsing-xml-lxml-objectify/), but the code above doesn't work as expected.

On a different tack, still better would be able to read the entire XML tree into a Python dictionary, with each element as the key and each text as the element item(s). I found out that something like this might be possible using lxml objectify, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve it.

One really big problem I have been finding when attempting to write XML parsing code in Python is that most of the "examples" provided are just too simple and entirely fictitious to be of much help -- or else they are just the opposite, using too complicated automatically-generated XML data!

Could anybody give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After posting this question, I found a simple solution [here](http://python.dzone.com/articles/using-lxmlobjectify-parse-xml).

So, my updated code becomes:

```
from lxml import objectify
    root = objectify.fromstring(xml_string) # xml_string contains the XML data above
    print root.title # returns the book title
    for para in root.abstract.iterchildren():
        print para # now returns the text of all paragraphs
    for keyword in root.keywordSet.iterchildren():
        print keyword # now returns all keywords in the set
```

Comment: Indeed, @LukasGraf answer below also provides this same solution, but in a more pythonic way! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty simple using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('data.xml')

paragraphs = tree.xpath('/abstract/para/text()')
keywords = tree.xpath('/keywordSet/keyword/text()')

print paragraphs
print keywords
```

Output:

```
['First paragraph of the abstract', 'Second paragraph of the abstract']
['First keyword', 'Second keyword', 'Third keyword']
```

See [the XPath Tutorial at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for details on the XPath syntax.

In particular, the elements used in the expressions above use

- The `/` selector to select the root node / the immediate children.
- The `text()` operator to select the text node (the "textual content") of the respective elements.

---

Here's how it could be done using the Objectify API:

```
from lxml import objectify

root = objectify.fromstring(xml_string)

paras = [p.text for p in root.abstract.para]
keywords = [k.text for k in root.keywordSet.keyword]

print paras
print keywords
```

<s>It seems that `root.abstract.para` is actually [shorthand](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) for `root.abstract.para[0]`. So you need to explicitly use `element.iterchildren()` to access all child elements.</s>

That's not true, we obviously both misunderstood the Objectify API:
In order to iterate over the `para`s in `abstract`, you need to iterate over `root.abstract.para`, not `root.abstract` itself. It's weird, because you intuitively think about `abstract` as a collection or a container for its nodes, and that container would be represented by a Python iterable. But it's actually the `.para` selector that represents the sequence.

Comment: Sure, nice tip! But would it be possible to also achieve the same result using lxml objectfy?

Comment: It would, no doubt. But *particularly* for (deeply) nested structures where you want to traverse the tree, XPath is often *much* easier and readable.

Comment: Well, there is objectify.ObjectPath, but the examples provided are, well, sort of ugly... :-(

Comment: @user40893 updated my answer with an example of how it can be done using the Objectify API.

Comment: Note though that in the solution in your question, `para` is not actually a string, it's a `StringElement` object. It looks like a string if you print it, but depending on what you do with it later, you may need to access the actual string contents using `para.text`.

Comment: thanks again for this very helpful tip, indeed I was wondering about the difference between element.text and just element.