# How to read the xml data using the python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Here are my xml details

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="3.3" Fecha="2020-12-07T22:45:14" Serie="ACER" Folio="1351" Sello="HOkVbkR8xTpqJ2zlnnfOHZ8/+2C/vkgs4BrbOnJBy6Beq3VunkG31uGVTFi/dDeOZHynZciJ9TduRAjDy068wqDDIKbtFn5QP3G2rhaP5fcMvBAClDrpyh1DFdB0Eh7UalVu4x84QncuAHIJw0tTWSZGyVRMAu48Cc5RNme+VmdN/V5ngYk+lE1f0vA6jfNOpQYBsi/r3vQbYqP8PeLhLL1vDWW7o6qdyfTwZ40G8eJJCiCiVDphDELJVioVuYPthW015v8Chdzb0Kw9xZxn4vWlTJbKoudEpPRFS13zf5kFZk+gI3v/kd5IhMDlZAt7Nbpf0JMEVpj8oOtwgOL4nA==" FormaPago="03" NoCertificado="00001000000413604423" CondicionesDePago="Pago en una sola exhibición" SubTotal="21200.08" Moneda="MXN" Total="24592.09" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="06600" TipoCambio="1">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="IOM080418AP9" Nombre="IOS OFFICES DE MEXICO SA DE CV" RegimenFiscal="601"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="BRE190920DC7" Nombre="BIGBOX REGALOS S DE RL DE CV" UsoCFDI="G03"/>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto NoIdentificacion="401000100000312" ClaveProdServ="80161504" Cantidad="1.00" Unidad="Servicio" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="USO DE SUITE" ValorUnitario="21200.08" Importe="21200.08">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Base="21200.08" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="3392.01"/>
                </cfdi:Traslados>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

When I try to get creative all the tags using the tree it is give only the first tag only `<cfdi:Comprobante>` not all and also how to retrieve the value of the inner tag

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/home/user/Downloads/test.xml')
root = tree.xpath('/Comprobante/Emisor/Rfc/text()')
```

Comment: You can iterate over elements to get their nested elements `[elem for elem in tree]` where `tree`  is your `etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)` result.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370098/handling-nested-elements-with-python-lxml .

Comment: @Axe319 I have tried with xpath but not working.

Comment: @mzjn I want to get Emisor ->RFC tag and I have tried with tree.xpath('/Comprobante/Emisor/Rfc/text()') but it's give me error

Comment: You need to be aware of XML namespaces. And there is no `xpath()` method in ElementTree (but lxml has such a method).

Comment: Using a namespace: `tree.xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor/@Rfc', namespaces={'cfdi': 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3'})` where `tree` is an `lxml.etree` element. Reference https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes

Comment: Or simpler: `tree.xpath('//cfdi:Emisor/@Rfc', namespaces=tree.nsmap)`